# Validation in Miva store not allowing users to enter information into text boxes

Tags: miva

We are working on an online Miva store for a client which can be viewed here: http://www.labwear.com/shop/metrohm.htm. When a customer goes through all the steps: selects lab coat color, selects size, selects logo, selects embroidery color, and selects embroidery style users cannot enter anything into the embroidery name text box. If anyone has any idea why this is happening please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Someone set the HTML5 attribute "readonly" on it.  Miva Merchant doesn't use the HTML5 doctype or attributes by default, so someone set this.  Take that off and see if it fixes the issue.

Also, you have JavaScript issues.  You're trying to declare variables, but you're doing them like this:

```
var var_mvt = 1964M
```

Instead of:

```
var var_mvt = "1964M"
```

So that's stopping the rest of the JavaScript from executing (which might be triggering the removal of the "readonly" attribute).

Comment: It appears javascript is setting the read only property. Also the var var_mvt is being assigned by what I can assume is a miva variable &mvt:product:code; I added the quotes around the miva variable with concatination like so: '"' + &mvt:product:code; + '"'; and it's still not working.

Comment: I tried that. still didn't work. I am looking for a method of removing the read-only attribute on the text boxes. I have tried to set the read-only property to false via java-script, I tried removing the attribute using the removeAttribute('readOnly') method, I looked for the text fields in the miva back-end to see if I could just remove the read only property from each text box and apparently miva builds the form from <mvt:item name="product_attributes" param="product:id" /> which I cannot find..

Comment: Well, what does your Product Attribute Template? That's where these get generated.  It's really difficult to diagnose this without code or access.  Try and update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: Also, you're calling functions which don't exist.  There's this "FillCheck_PRODUCT_CODE" (where PRODUCT_CODE is the product code) function that executes each KeyUp on these inputs.  There are a few different things going on here.  You should talk to whoever wrote the JavaScript to find out what they were trying to accomplish.